# Mybatis @Autowired Mapper not injectes Mapper interface and throws NPE

Tags: interface, mybatis, mapper

I am trying to inject Mybatis Interface from Child project parent in Maven structure.But Mapper is not injected properly and it throws NullPointerException .Please help me why Mybatis interface mapper not injected properly?

Comment: You need to post your code at the very least so people can have an idea as to what the issue is.

Comment: You should show here your attempt to solve the problem yourself by putting some code.

Comment: I am assuming you are using Spring, Have you included the packages of the child project in the `@ComponentScan` ?